# Testing a Django app in many separate threads

Tags: python, django, multithreading, testing

I'd like to run my Django app's tests in several threads (possibly dozens) in parallel. This is because my app spends almost all of its time waiting for remote requests, and I reckon that if I run the tests in parallel, they would all work at the same time without slowing each other down, and the whole suite would be over pretty quickly.

But... Tests are currently running with Django's `runserver`, which is single-threaded. So it won't be able to serve dozens of requests in parallel.

(I use Django's `./manage.py test` with `django_nose` to invoke the tests.)

One idea I have is to use [`devserver`](https://github.com/dcramer/django-devserver) instead. The question is, will it automatically be used when invoking `./manage.py test`?

And another question is: I ran into `devserver` rather randomly, and I don't know whether it has any competitors that might be better. Does it?

Comment: http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201103/quick_and_dirty_multithreaded_django_dev_server.html to make mutli threaded it's very simple

Answer (score 0):

use uWSGI

```
pip install uwsgi
```

Create .ini for your project:

```
[uwsgi]
# set the http port
http = :8000
# change to django project directory
chdir = /var/www/myapp
# add /var/www to the pythonpath, in this way we can use the project.app format
pythonpath = /var/www
# set the project settings name
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myapp.settings
# load django
module = django.core.handlers.wsgi:WSGIHandler()
```

Start it with built-in http server

```
uwsgi --ini django.ini --async 10
```

async — number of threads

http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/Quickstart

http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/Doc095

Answer (score -1):

I've recently began delving into django-celery which is an asynchronous task queue for django. It allows you to queue up tasks to run asynchronously so that you don't have to wait for responses. It's simple to install and get started and it would allow your application to utilize asynchronous queueing instead of just your test suite.

http://django-celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/index.html

Comment: Celery is awesome, but I don't see how it's a solution to my problem.

Comment: I was thinking that if you submit each request that your app makes as its own task, they'll run asynchronously and you won't have to wait for each response before executing the next.